# как вызвать из go cmd сомманду для win ну например dir, только простой пример пожалуйста?

Tags: golang

если в си system("dir"); то как на go

Comment: на https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#pkg-overview примеры для nix. для windows с dos командами они не подошли.

Comment: код :c:/go/bin/go.exe build [C:/Users/User/go/src/mycmd2]
Успех: процесс завершился с кодом 0.
C:/Users/User/go/src/mycmd2/mycmd2.exe  [C:/Users/User/go/src/mycmd2]
2020/01/29 14:27:49 exec: "dir": executable file not found in %PATH%

Answer (score 1):

https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#pkg-overview

Смотри примеры для функций Start и Run

Comment: @user369523, для windows попробуй добавить cmd /C, т.е cmd := exec.Command("cmd", "/C", "dir")

Comment: Можешь поделиться кодом? В теории он должен быть таким https://play.golang.org/p/V-korSfK0jJ

Answer (score 1):

Поскольку `dir` это консольная команда, а не приложение (исполняемого файла dir.exe не существует), то для её выполнения вам надо запустить консоль и в качестве аргумента передать имя команды (ключ `/C` означает "выполнить команду и завершить работу").

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {
    cmd := exec.Command("cmd.exe", "/C", "dir")

    stdoutStderr, err := cmd.CombinedOutput()

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("%s\n", stdoutStderr)
}
```

Если нужно запустить обычный exe, то просто указываете его в качестве первого параметра функции [exec.Command](https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#Command). При этом, если исполняемый файл не находится в `%PATH%` или в текущей директории, вам надо указать абсолютный путь к нему (обратите внимание, я использовал обратные кавычки, т.к. в путях под windows используется обратный слэш `\` в качестве разделителя пути):

```
cmd := exec.Command(`c:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe`)
```